# Logging when an Azure (Basic) Web App Exceeds Quotas

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Running a basic, free Windows Azure Web application for testing purposes I often exceed the CPU Time (short) quota of 3 minutes.

For example, when trialling the image optimisation Nuget package AzureImageOptimizer which is implemented as a Web Job, the initial optimisation run exceeded the limit and stopped the server.

I notice these events are not being recorded in the Web App's Activity Log. Why?

Questions:

- Are these events logged?
- Is it because this is a Free Web App?
- Can the Web App be configured so that they are logged?
- Is there an alternative way to catch these
  events?

Bonus question:

- Can I receive a notification before a quota is exceeded?

Comment: After researching this a little it appears an Alert can be added to the Web App under the Monitoring section with a trigger condition based on CPU Time. For example, to send an email if CPU Time exceeds 160 seconds over the last 5 minutes. This would catch and log the events in the Activity Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these events logged?

No. If an application in its usage exceeds the CPU (short), CPU (Day), or bandwidth quota then the application will be stopped until the quota re-sets. No log will be written to any place.

> Is it because this is a Free Web App?

Both Free and Shared Plan have the resources limits.

> Can the Web App be configured so that they are logged?

I also haven't found any way to do it.

> Is there an alternative way to catch these events?

Since you are using WebJob, you could add a CancellationToken parameter in your function. If the Web App is stopped. The IsCancellationRequested property will be set to true before the function stopped.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task.Run(new Action(longTimeJob), cancellationToken);
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The function has been Cancelled since the Web App is stopped!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the information I captured from Azure WebJobs Dashboard when the Web App is stopped.

```
[06/07/2017 07:52:53 > 9d3635: INFO] The function has been Cancelled since the Web App is stopped!
[06/07/2017 07:52:53 > 9d3635: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[06/07/2017 07:52:53 > 9d3635: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[06/07/2017 07:52:54 > 9d3635: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
```